# passing array of pointers to function in Vivado HLS (SDSoC 2018)

Tags: c++, fpga, xilinx, vivado, vivado-hls

I am working on accelerating a C++ function using SDSoC 2018.3 Vivado HLS. This function simply takes an array of pointers (allocated in the PS using sds_alloc). Then, it loops over this array,  extracts each element of it (which is an address to a DDR memory), and reads the data located in this address.

Here is a simple function that demonstrates the idea:

```
float get_data_from_DDR(float *data_addresses_array[10], unsigned int size)

{

    float * address;

    float sum = 0;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i< 10; i++)

    {

         address = data_addresses_array[i];

         for(unsigned int j = 0; j<size; j++ ) {

            sum += address[j];

        }

    }

   return sum;

}
```

The issue is that, SDSoC raises an error if I pass array of pointers as an argument for the top level function.

After digging in "ug902" manual of Vivado, I found that:

> “Vivado HLS supports pointers to pointers for synthesis but does not support them on the top-level interface, that is, as argument to the top-level function. If you use a pointer to pointer in multiple functions, Vivado HLS inlines all functions that use the pointer to pointer. Inlining multiple functions can increase run time.”

I don't know how to tackle this problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a way to overcome this limitation directly, but perhaps you could pass an array of offsets instead, and then use these offsets as indices into an array that is placed in DDR memory.